# CreateJS - Sprite / ButtonHelper Issues

Tags: createjs, animate-cc

I am having an issue with creating buttons in an Animate CC HTML 5 canvas project.  I've tried creating a MovieClip instance in my library, setting a linkage name and creating a frame in the MovieClip for each state, labelled  as "out", "over", "down" and "hit".

Using the ButtonHelper class in CreateJS has "worked", to a degree, producing a functioning button with rollover state, until I try to reposition the button else where on the stage using the .x and .y properties.   When I do this, the hit state seems to "separate" from the rest of the MovieClip - i.e.  to trigger the "rollover" frame,  I would have to mouse over the hit state much further down and to the right of the stage.

My Animate CC trial has now expired, so I am trying to solve my issues with using the CreateJS libraries with plain old fashioned HTML. I have created a spritesheet PNG file with three 50px x 50px images in it, which equals 150px X 50px.  I have created an HTML doc and Javascript code, which follow below, but when the states of the Sprite button do not change when I click "down" on it or mouse "over" it.

I wonder if anything could pass some ideas my way?  There might well be a simple error in what I've written, I'm working by myself and slowing going "code-blind" to it.

Thanks very much,

Dave

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sprite and Spritesheet Testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easeljs-0.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/preloadjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/soundjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/tweenjs-0.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/defaults.css" />
    </head>

    <body onload="init();">
        <h1>Using Sprites, SpriteSheets and ButtonHelper</h1>
        <p>Below should be some example buttons.  Hopefully this functionality can be recreated within Animate CC using the CreateJS libraries.</p>

        <!-- CreateJS content will be displayed here -->
        <canvas id="t26Canvas" width="749" height="737" class="setupCanvas">
            <h1>The internet browser you are currently using does not support the &lt;canvas/&gt; HTML 5 element.</h1>
        </canvas>

    </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
/* Javascript required by the example page */

var HTML5Stage;
var spritesheet;
var data;
var myButton;
var myButtonHelper;

function init() {
    // Get the HTML5 <canvas/> element we are going to be using for the CreateJS content.
    HTML5Stage = new createjs.Stage("t26Canvas");
    // Set usable on touch devices
    createjs.Touch.enable(HTML5Stage);
    // Enable capturing of mouse rollover events
    HTML5Stage.enableMouseOver(30);
    setupSpriteSheet();
    addTestButton();
}


function setupSpriteSheet() {
        data = {
         images: ["images/ui/buttonsprites.png"],
         frames: {width: 50, height: 50},
         animations: {
            out: 0,
            over: 1,
            down: 2
         }
     };
    spritesheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet(data);
}

function addTestButton() {
    myButton = new createjs.Sprite(spritesheet);
    myButtonHelper = new createjs.ButtonHelper(myButton);
    HTML5Stage.addChild(myButton).set({x: 300, y: 100})
    HTML5Stage.update();
}
```

Comment: Try adding `createjs.Ticker.on("tick", HTML5Stage)` to your `init` method. Right now, the stage is not being updated after the initial `addTestButton` call, so visual changes aren't displayed.

Comment: Thank you, that seemed to be just what I was looking forward.  Everything seems to be working as expected now!